# Is there any way to stop AWS from starting CodePipeline automatically if I deploy it via CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

If you create a CodePipeline via CloudFormation. It starts it automatically, that can be a problem because the pipeline can rewrite the same stack...

Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So the correct answer is...

1. Commit your code before you deploy for the first time
2. Deploy *only* the pipeline
3. Let Code Pipeline do its thing

99% of cases it will finish sooner than your machine.

Comment: It's not clear why your own answer was the accepted answer. The question you asked was "How do I prevent the pipeline from automatically starting after creation." This answer, while it might have suited your need at the time, is definitely not helpful in regard to how to prevent the pipeline from starting after creation. @dummymjs really has the correct answer, followed by a second best (mostly from quoting the doc) from Marcin.

Answer (score 4):

Had same issue, I don't want a pipeline launch on pipeline creation (which is the default beahviour).

Best solution I fount is :

1. Create an EventBridge rule which catch the pipelineExecution on
   pipeline creation
2. Stop the pipeline execution from the lambda triggered

Rule looks like this :

```
{
  "source": ["aws.codepipeline"],
  "detail-type": ["CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "state": ["STARTED"],
    "execution-trigger": {
      "trigger-type": ["CreatePipeline"]
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there seem to be no way of this this. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create.html) clearly states that a newly created pipeline immediately starts running:

> Now that you've created your pipeline, you can view it in the console. The **pipeline starts to run after you create it**.

The initial run will always happen. Subsequent runs depend on your source action. For example, if you use CodeCommit as your source, you can **disable CloudWatch Event** that triggers the pipeline.

Thus if you want to use CodePipeline in your project, you have to design it so that it does not causes any issues due to immediate start.

Comment: "Thus if you want to use CodePipeline in your project, you have to design it so that it does not causes any issues due to immediate start."

Any idea how?

Comment: @artit91 Unfortunately, from your very short description of the issue, its difficult to say anything. You would have to write new question with all relevant details, such as what is the architecture of your pipeline (e.g. what is the source stage), what is its outcome, what do you mean it can "rewrite the same stack"? Which stack?

Comment: just build in a disabled stage transition after the initial source stage.

Comment: @pkarfs Yes, you could do this using [StageTransition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codepipeline-pipeline-disableinboundstagetransitions.html) but the first read of the source will still execute. Maybe you can add an answer. It seems as a good compromise?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Event rule from automatically starting your pipeline.
Go to [**Amazon EventBridge** -> **Rules**](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/events/home#/rules) and disable the rule that notifies the CodePipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Further to Marcin's comment, it would seem there are 2 approaches you can take which would limit the run of the pipeline.

1. Create a **disabled StageTransition** or **Manual Approval** stage directly after the **Source** stage. This would prevent the pipeline executing any other action aside from getting the source which would have no impact or capability to re-write anything.
2. Alternatively if your source stage is from a repository, you can opt to handle the pipeline triggers yourself by disabling the **PollForSourceChanges** parameter in your cloudformation template.

   ```
   Pipeline:
     Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
     Properties:
       Name: *NAME*
       RoleArn: *IAMROLE*
       Stages:
         - Name: Source
           Actions:
             - Name: CodeCommitSourceAction
               RunOrder: 1
               ActionTypeId:
                 Category: Source
                 Provider: CodeCommit
                 Owner: AWS
                 Version: '1'
               OutputArtifacts:
                 - Name: Source
               Configuration:
                 RepositoryName: *REPOSITORYNAME*
                 BranchName: *BRANCH*
                 PollForSourceChanges: "false" #prevents codepipeline polling repository for  changes.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this myself and a search brought me here. In my case I'm using Terraform - same outcome.

The event bridge stuff looks too complicated for me and I don't want to try to create the pipeline first with manual run enabled, then update it again enabled.

So I started looking at what environment strings are available to the build that may help.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

I found this one **CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER**

If CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER is 1 then it's simply the first time this pipeline is running since it's been created.
Just add a line that aborts the build if CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER is 1.

```
- if [ $CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER -eq 1 ]; then echo 'aborting first build' && exit 1; fi
```